# MVC4 Code First - IList is not filled with data / NullPointer Exception in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I try to write a Blog with MVC4 and have problems with the `Post - Comment (1 to n)`, as well as with the `Post - Tag (n to m)` relationship, using code first.

Tag:

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment:

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Post:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Using this code first, I get a database which looks like:

`Comment n to 1 Post n to m Tag`

Where for the `n to 1` the foreign key to `Post` is in `Comment` and for the `n to m` a Cross Table was created.

Now, I created a `Controller` as well as a `View` to create a new `Post` with `Tags`.

When I look into my database, everything is filled correctly. The `Post` and `Tags` exist, and the Cross Table is filled with the `IDs`.

But now, when I want to render the `Post` in my `View` I want to get the data with `@post.Tags`, where `@post` represents my currently selected `Post` which has the correct Data (`Title, Name etc`), but for `Tags`, which is the `IList<Tag>` from my `Model` I get a `NullPointer Exception`. (The same goes for `@post.Comments`)

Although, when creating the `Post`:

```
new Post() { ID = -1, Tags=new List<Tag>(), Comments=new List<Comment>(), DateTime = DateTime.Now };
```

**Edit:**
When using `virtual`, I get a System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException.  There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

**Solution**
I was missing the `virtual` Keyword as well as to invoke the `Include` Method. To get the Method I had to use `System.Data.Entity`

Now it works, thank you both

Comment: Did you try including the child entities. e.g. dbContext.Post.where(predicate).Include(post=>post.Comments) ?

Comment: There is no Include Method I could invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to make the `Tags` and `Comments` properties of your `Post` class `virtual` so they can be lazy-loaded.

```
public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
```

Comment: When using `virtual`, I get a System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException. 
`There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first`

Comment: @Loki Add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` to your connection string if you want to use lazy loading. Otherwise, use Include to load the related entities (eager loading).

Comment: @CarlesCompany Also a nice way to do it. I probably go with this one